# Assigning multiple authors to a channel entry

Tags: relationships

I need to add multiple authors on post, but I don't know how to do implement this. I'm a new to ExpressionEngine.

My articles have also a multiple bibliography, and I have the same problem, which is how in general to manage a master-detail relationships in ExpressionEngine.

With the new 2.6 relationship, is easy to display related category, but I cannot find a way to   insert them.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on how you're handling authorship. There's only so much you can do with the custom fields in the member module, and assigning multiple authors that way is less than ideal, but you could pretty easily create an "authors" channel - whether you tie that to your member logins using one of the "members as channels" add-ons is up to you - and that would allow you to use the native relationship field in 2.6 to assign multiple authors to a single post.  I've done it that way before with Playa rather than the native relationship field, but the idea is the same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree. For multiple authors you'd really need to go with an addon such as [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) or [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) where you can bring member information out into their own Channels and then use a relationship field to attach them to each entry. Without a lot of hacking I can't think of a way the default Member module could handle it.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it as well.

Comment: And how does that work "assign multiple authors" how do you check for access rights on safecracker and control panel?